# How many items are stored in an iPad clipboard?

Tags: ios, ipad

In iPad how many items can be stored in the clipboard?

How does one select from one of the past entries?

Where does it get stored and how to access it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One item (independent of the type, can be text, can be an image) can be stored at a time in the clipboard and it is not possible to access past entries. The clipboard is stored in memory.

Comment: And is it same for images and text?

Comment: it's the same for everything, clipboard is ephemeral & stores only the last copied item, whatever it may be. It is immediately & completely replaced by the next copy action.